# When new user connects the previous connection becomes the new user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've been playing around a bit with NodeJS and recently socket.IO, I come from PHP development and try to understand really how to work with Node and socket.IO

I started building a chat app and when I were to test it on different devices I noticed that when I for instance log in to another account through my phone, the browser window updates and gets the same user as I logged into on my phone

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: 0.5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chatLogin">
        <input type="text" name="password" id="username" placeholder="Username..." /><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password..." /><br>
        <button id="chatLoginBtn">Login / Register</button>
    </div>
    <div id="chatWindow">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chatWindow").hide();
        $("#chatLoginBtn").click(function(){
            socket.emit('loginForm', {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            });
        });

    });





    socket.on('returnValue', function(msg) {
            var html = '<ul id="messages"></ul>' + 
            '<form id="sendMsg" action="">' + 
            '<input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>' + 
            '</form>';
            $("#chatLogin").html("").hide();
            $("#chatWindow").html(html).show();

              $('#sendMsg').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
                var time = Date.now();
                var msg = $("#m").val();
                var data = [time, msg];
                socket.emit('chat', data);
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
        });

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var phpPass = require('node-php-password');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

// DECLARE the variables we will be using

// These does not change
let userCount = 0;

// These are declared to be later set

var displayName;
var userDataID;


// POOL MySQL Connection

var pool    =    mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit   :   100,
      host              :   'localhost',
      user              :   'root',
      password          :   '....',
      port              :   '3306',
      database          :   '....',
      debug             :   false
});

// session & cookieParser

/*var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: "keyboard cat"
});

io.use(function (socket, next) {
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(cookieParser());*/

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var hashPassword;



function checkUser(user, Password, userID) {
    pool.getConnection(function(error,connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE `username` = '"+user+"' LIMIT 1",function(error,rows){
            if (!error) {
            var hashPassword = rows[0].password;

            if (phpPass.verify(Password, hashPassword)) {
                console.log(Password);
                console.log(hashPassword);
                console.log("Went well");

                // UPDATE user database with current socketID

                connection.query("UPDATE accounts SET `socketID` = '"+userID+"' WHERE `username` = '"+user+"'",function(error,result){
                    connection.release();
                    if (!error) {
                        connection.query("SELECT id,displayName,username,email,fullName,dateofBirth,created,lastSignedIn FROM accounts WHERE socketID = '"+userID+"' LIMIT 1",function(error,userData){
                            if (!error) {
                                displayName = userData[0].displayName;
                                userDataID = userData[0].id;
                                console.log("Current user: " + userData[0].displayName);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Error" + error);
                            }

                        });

                        console.log("No error" + result);
                    } else {
                        console.log("We found error" + error);
                    }
                });

                // send to function to gather all needed info from database and save for the current session



                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("Wrong pass");
                return false;
            }

            console.log(hashPassword);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            }
        });
        connection.on('error', function(error) {

        });
    });
        return true;
};


io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    var req = socket.request;
    var userID = socket.id;
// When connection is inited

    userCount++;

    console.log('User connected' + userCount);

    // Take the data from login and pass to check if it is valid

    socket.on("loginForm", function(data){
        const user = data.username,
        pass = data.password;
        //console.log(checkUser(user, pass));
        if (checkUser(user, pass, userID)) {
            io.emit('returnValue', 'hi');
        }
    });

    function joinRoom(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("Joined " + room);
        return io.emit('chat', "Joined new room " + room);
    }

    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        socket.join(data);
        console.log("Joined " + data);
    });


    socket.on('chat', (data) => {

        /* Array: Data;
        [0] Time
        [1] Message


        [2] socketID
        [3] User        
        */

        var msg = data[1];
        var time = data[0];



        // Calc time

        var date = new Date(time);
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var formatted = hours + ":" + minutes;
        if (minutes < 10) return minutes = "0" + minutes;
        var dateFormatted = "[" + formatted + "] ";

        //data.push(user);

        pool.getConnection(function(error,connection) {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO `chat_messages` (userID, socketID, message, time) VALUES ('"+userDataID+"', '"+userID+"', '"+msg+"', '"+time+"')",function(error,rows){
            connection.release();
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Success");
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        });


        if (msg.startsWith('/me')) return io.emit('chat', dateFormatted + displayName + msg.substring(3));
        if (msg.startsWith('/join')) return joinRoom(msg.substring(6));
        if (msg.startsWith('/rooms')) return console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);

        return io.emit('chat', dateFormatted + displayName + ' said: ' + msg);
        //console.log(displayName + 'said:' + msg);
    });

// When user disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {

    userCount--;

    console.log('User disconnected!' + userCount);
  });


});

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on *:3000');
});
```

I do not get any errors and it counts the number of users correctly

The problem is that the user first logged in gets switched to the last logged in user

How do I make the user session unique and so multiple clients can be logged in into different accounts?

Comment: I would start by investigating if and how `userId` and/or `socketId` could be the same for both users. I am immediately concerned with the logic following `// UPDATE user database with current socketID` because it is mutating `socketId`, so it could be possible the logic is setting it to the same socket as the previous user.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed an issue: `var userDataID;`
It's a global variable. Each time a new user log ing, the `userDataID` will be updated. It's always the ID of the newest logged user. Then, all new messages will be stored in the database with the userDataID.
EX:
 - Log in by account A on window, the userDataID = 1;
 - send some messages to server, these message will be stored with userID = 1
 - Log in by account B on iphone, the userDataID will be updated, it's = 2 now.
 - send some messages from windown & iphone. all these message will be stored with userID 2.

I think that's the error you got.

Should store userID in cookie or session.